# rcleartool login failing with Errorlevel 1

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client

I am trying to use rcleartool command to login to ClearCase Remote Client, when I try to login I get this issue

**rcleartool login -lname userid -server https://something.com/cc -pas mypassword**

You are successfully logged in as "userid" to server "https://something.com/cc".

**But when I run echo %ERRORLEVEL% after above command I get 1 as the output.**

When I run logout after this

**rcleartool logout -server https://something.com/cc**

You are successfully logged out of the server https://something.com/cc

**And after logout when I run echo %ERRORLEVEL% it gives 0 as output.**

I am not sure why this is happening, I can login with the ClearTeam Explorer to the remote client I gave same details as the rcleartool command just that **I had added group as well in the preferences tab of Clearteam Explorer**, do I need to add group as well somewhere in rcleartool configuration ?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file at the users home directory with name **.ccrccli_pref** ( c:\users\username )

we need to specify the group name in that file, content of that file can be checked with command **rcleartool set**

Need to take care of \ in the file if your group name is domain\mygroupname we need to put it as domain\\mygroupname also need to put the server url in the file, after that login works fine and I can connect to clearcase

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`rcleartool` man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/rcleartool.htm), check first if this is more reliable than `%ERRORLEVEL%`

```
rcleartool -status
```

That would return the status (0 or 1) of each `rcleartool` subcommand that is executed (however, that would be in an interactive session).
If the issue is the same, then yes, try and add the group in your configuration.

Comment: I tried that before rcleartool -status but it does not return any value in the prompt, as I was trying to run the login with jenkins and it was failing hence I checked %ERRORLEVEL% and reason of its failure was the errorlevel that it was throwing. Do you know where I can  add the group in configuration ? struggling to find the particular file.

Comment: @bhardwajme but what was the `%ERRORLEVEL%` value after a `rcleartool -status` (itself executed just after your `rcleartool login`)?

Comment: actually when I run rcleartool -status it goes into the rcleartool prompt ( rcleartool 1>)and I can not run the %ERRORLEVEL% there

Comment: @bhardwajme OK, so not appropriate for a non-interactive rcleartool session.

Comment: I ran rcleartool -status and then inside rcleartool prompt I again ran login command it again gave successful login output but it gave status as 1

Comment: Any idea where can I put the group name in the configuration, tried googling but couldn't find any links @VonC

Comment: @bhardwajme No, unless it is part of the existing parameter like `group/username` instead of just `username`.

Comment: hey I somehow was able to solve it, there is a file at the users home directory with name .ccrccli_pref ( c:\users\username ) we need to specify the group name in that file, content of that file can be checked with command rcleartool set , need to take care of (\) in the file if your group name is domain\mygroupname we need to put it as domain\\mygroupname also need to put the server url in the file, after that login works fine and I can connect to clearcase @VonC